# Sort lists of vertices {indegrees, outdegrees} by indegree

Tags: functions, syntax, version-9, sorting

```
in = VertexInDegree[F];
out = VertexOutDegree[F];
```

I want both in and out to be ordered by in. Example: graph has nodes a,b,c with indegrees 1,2,0 and outdegrees 0,1,2. I want lists in = {0,1,2} and out = {2,0,1}.

How do I do this? I tried

```
in = Sort[VertexInDegree[F]];
out = VertexOutDegree[F][[Ordering@in]];
```

, but this didn't give the expected result.

Comment: You want to use `Ordering` on the data before sorting. Try `out = VertexOutDegree[F][[Ordering@VertexInDegree[F]]]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
g = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[10, 0.2], DirectedEdges -> True];
inout = Through[{VertexInDegree, VertexOutDegree}[g]]
(* {{2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}} *)
#\[Transpose][[Ordering[First@#]]]\[Transpose] &@inout
(* {{0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1}}*)
```